# Non trivial subgroups in cyclic group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups

Following on from my amazing journey on better understanding group theory and number theory, I know want to understand how one finds non-trivial subgroups in a cyclic group G

So for example, I want to find five non-trivial subgroups from the following cyclic group  $G = \mathbb{Z}_{97}^{\times}$

The order of  $G = \mathbb{Z}_{97}^{\times}$ is of course 96 as 97 is prime and thus we do 97-1=96.

Now we also know that the factors of 96 are {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96}.

The question is what is a non-trivial group and how would I find non-trivial groups, five at least?

Comment: If $\langle a \rangle=G$, then the element of the form  $a^k$ will give you elements of other orders as well (depending on $k$). Those elements will generate the subgroups. So first find $a$ for $\Bbb{Z}_{97}^{\times}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Sorry Sir I don't suppose you could kindly provide a more detailed answer for this answer please? I am new to a lot of this group theory and number theory and I am very intrigued and interested to learn a lot more.

Comment: It might help you to note that no square can have order $96\pmod {97}$, since $a^{96}\equiv 1 \implies \left(a^2\right)^{48}\equiv 1$.  So I'd start by looking at $4,9,16,...$.

Comment: As a suggestion:  start with a smaller group.  Why start with one so big?  Take the the cyclic group of order $12$...that is, start with $p=13$ rather than $p=97$.

Comment: There is a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of 96. Once you find a generator $a$ for $G$ (any integer relatively prime to 96 will do), the subgroup of order $d$ will be generated by $a^{96/d}$. The values $d=1$ and $d=96$ will yield the trivial group and the whole group, respectively. So, you have 10 divisors to choose from to generate proper and non-trivial groups.

Answer (score 6):

A subgroup is defined to be "proper" if it is not the whole group.  A proper subgroup is non-trivial if it is not the subgroup of size $1$ consisting of only the identity element.

Since $G$ is cyclic of order $96$, there is an element $a \in G$ such that $G = \{a^n ~ \vert ~ 1 \leq n \leq 96 \}$.  Find a value of $a$ that works (there will be more than one).  Then if $ 1 \lt m \text{ and } m \vert 96$, the set $H=\{(a^m)^k ~ \vert ~ 1 \leq k \leq \frac{96}{m} \}$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$.

You will find it a useful exercise to prove that $H$ as I have defined it is in fact a subgroup, and that $H$ is proper $ \iff \gcd (m, 96) \gt 1$.  It should be clear that $H$ is non-trivial unless $96 \vert m$.

Comment: It is more common to call *trivial* only the subgroup with one element. A subgroup that is not the entire group is called *proper*.

Comment: Revised to reflect this comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sir I don't suppose you can do a worked example for me please Would be great to see how it all works in practice

Comment: The answer of Anurag A below gives you a worked example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\Bbb{Z}_{97}^{\times}$. Consider $2 \in G$.

*What is the order of $2$ in $G$?*

The possible orders are divisors of $96$, namely $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96\}$. Of course the order is not $1$. But instead of checking each power separately, we can try a different approach. Note that $96=2^5 \cdot 3$. So we will determine if 
$$2^{96/2}=2^{48}\equiv 1 \pmod{97} \qquad \text{ or} \qquad 2^{96/3}=2^{32}\equiv 1 \pmod{97}.$$
If neither of these holds, then the order of $2$ will be $96$, hence it will be a generator. Unfortunately, (you can try it) $2^{48} \equiv 1 \pmod{97}$. This means the order of $2$ is $\leq 48$. In fact, we can show that it is $48$. So $\langle 2 \rangle$ will be a subgroup of order $48$.

Now try the same approach with $5$ instead of $2$. You will see that
$$5^{96/2}=5^{48}\not\equiv 1 \pmod{97} \qquad \text{ and} \qquad 5^{96/3}=5^{32}\not\equiv 1 \pmod{97}.$$

This shows that order of $5$ is $96$ and hence it is a generator of $G$.

Now what will be the order of say $5^3$?  Suppose it is $t$, then
$$5^{3t} \equiv 1 \pmod{97}.$$ 
This means $96 \mid 3t$. The smallest such $t$ is $32$. So the subgroup 
$$\langle 5^3 \rangle=\{(5^3)^k \, | \, k =1,2, \ldots\}$$ 
has order $32$. 
Likewise we can show that the order of $5^8$ is $12$. So the subgroup 
$$\langle 5^{8} \rangle=\{(5^{8})^k \, | \, k =1,2, \ldots\}$$ 
has order $12$ and so on.

Now use different powers of $5$ to generate subgroups of different orders. There are results which can make things go fast but I am deliberately avoiding those here so that you can develop your own understanding first.

Hopefully you can pick up from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir, why did you use 2 as the base?

Comment: @user23473433819233d I wanted to show you an example of how to find a generator as well as a proper subgroup of a cyclic group. There is nothing specific about choosing $2$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a smaller group.   Say, $\Bbb Z_{11}^×$.

The order is $10$ and it's cyclic.   Let's get a generator.   Since $2^5\cong{10}\pmod{11}$ and $2^2\cong4\pmod{11}$, the result is that $2$ is a generator (since $2$ does not have order $1,2$ or $5$).

Now all the subgroups will be of the form $\langle 2^k\rangle$ for some $k$.

In fact,  $\vert\langle 2^k\rangle \vert=\dfrac{10}{\operatorname {gcd}(10,k)}$.

The situation is just the same for $\Bbb Z_{97}^×$.  The finding of a generator is just a little more cumbersome, because of the size of the group.

For any $\Bbb Z_p^×$, the situation is the same.